# Sequelize - Cascade delete 3 tables

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to cascade delete data throught 3 associated tables in sequelize.

The models I have created are as follows.
[image: Schema]

Users Model:

```html
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Users = sequelize.define('Users', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
    },
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Users.belongsToMany(models.Books, {
          through: {
            model: models.History
          },
          foreignKey: 'userId',
          onDelete: 'cascade'
        });
      }
    }
  });

  return Users;
};
```

Books Model:

```html
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Books = sequelize.define('Books', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
    },
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Books.belongsToMany(models.Users, {
          through: {
            model: models.History
          },
          foreignKey: 'bookId',
          onDelete: 'cascade'
        });
      }
    }
  });

  return Books;
};
```

History Model:

```html
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var History = sequelize.define('History', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    bookId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    from: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false
    },
    to: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
    },
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE
  });

  return History;
};
```

When I try to cascade delete the Users object and all data about that user History from History table I have got following error:

update or delete on table "Users" violates foreign key constraint "History_userId_fkey" on table "History"

When I try do the same from Books I have got following error:

update or delete on table "Users" violates foreign key constraint "History_bookId_fkey" on table "History"

If I don't want to have that error I have first delete row from History then I can delete row about User/Book.

How to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share your code where you do the delete

Comment: Issue resolved. I have to recreate DB.